# Can you combine toHaveBeenCalledWith and toHaveBeenCalledTimes in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am using these two separate assertions in a Jasmine unit test.

```
expect(spyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedArgument);
expect(spyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expectedCount);
```

If I understand correctly these will confirm the following.

- The function is called with `expectedArgument` at least once, and
- The function is called a total of `expectedCount` times.

What I want to do is confirm that the function is called with `expectedArgument` exactly `expectedCount` times. In other words I want to count only the number of calls in which the argument matches.

I realize I could do my own counting with a fake...

```
var callCount = 0;
spyOn(myInstance, 'myFunction').and.callFake(arg => {
  if (arg === expectedArgument) {
    callCount++;
  }
});

...

expect(callCount).toEqual(expectedCount);
```

...but that does not have the readability of the previous syntax and feels like reinventing the wheel. I have not used Jasmine all that much so I wonder if I'm missing something.

Is there a way to make my assertion using built-in Jasmine matchers? Alternatively, is there another way to obtain similarly readable syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get more detailed information from the spy using `calls`. You can look at each call and its arguments like this:

```
expect(spyFunction.calls.count()).toBe(2)
expect(spyFunction.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual(/* args for 1st call */)
expect(spyFunction.calls.argsFor(1)).toEqual(/* args for 2nd call */)
```

See [Jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Spy_calls.html) for details.